# update query when check the checkbox with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a checkbox. 
if I check or uncheck the check box then a update query should be run with Ajax call.

If checks the checkbox then 1 should be update and if uncheck then 0 should be update.
 But it is not working.

**Checkbox is:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test_done" value="<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>" <?php if(($row1['test_done'])=='1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?> data-toggle="checkbox">
```

In above $row1['id'] and $row1['test_done'] are columns name, which are coming from another select query.

**Ajax Is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test_done").click(function(){    
    var val = $(this).val();
         if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
         url: "test_done.php", 
         data: {val:val,apply:'1'} 

         });
         }
         else
         {
         $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
         url: "test_done.php", 
         data: {val:val,apply:'0'} 

         });

         }
      });
   });
 </script>
```

**test_done.php is:**

```
include_once("connection.php");
if($_POST['apply']=='1')
{
$val = $_POST['val'];   
 mysql_query("update patient_package_details set test_done='1' where id='$val'") or die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
$val = $_POST['val'];   
mysql_query("update patient_package_details set test_done='0' where id='$val'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql*` functions for database connectivity. These functions are deprecated in newer versions of php. Use `mysqli*` OR `PDO`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and suggestion.  But my code is not working.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: When I click on checkbox then nothing happens. Means update query is not executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `change` event instead of `click` event on checkbox. Check if checkbox is checked then send 1 otherwise 0. on php side as we are sending both values, so you will get value using post. You don't need to check value for `$_POST["apply"]`. I have set the value of `apply` variable, so only one query will work.

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var apply = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: "test_done.php",
        data: {val: val, apply: apply}
    });
});
```

**test_done.php**:

```
include_once("connection.php");
$val = $_POST['val'];   
$apply = $_POST['apply'];   
mysql_query("update patient_package_details set test_done='$apply' where id='$val'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It is updating only first row. When I click on second row checkbox, then nothing happens

Comment: I have updated the answer. Use selector `$("input:checkbox")` instead of  `$("#test_done")`

Comment: I want to know one thing, that what will be better mysqli or PDO?

Comment: Checkout here https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059